# JS: how to use Object.assign to duplicate properties into an array of objects?

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

I'm trying to duplicate key-value pairs from one object into each distinct object inside an array.

```js
const propsToDuplicate = {
  foo: 'foo',
  bar: 'bar'
};

const items = [{
    num: 1
  },
  {
    num: 2
  }
];

const result = items.map(item => {
  console.log('item: ', item);
  const moar = Object.assign(propsToDuplicate, item);
  console.log('item with more stuff: ', moar);
  return moar;
});

console.log(result);
```

Questions:

1. Why do I end up with two instances of the object with `num` = 2?
2. How can I perform this operation so that the final result is as below?

Desired result:

```
[ { foo: 'foo', bar: 'bar', num: 1 },
  { foo: 'foo', bar: 'bar', num: 2 } ]
```

Here is the sandbox:

https://repl.it/@montrealist/array-map-and-object-assign-weirdness

Comment: The workaround is to `return JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(moar));` from inside the `map()`.

Comment: because `moar === propsToDuplicate` in your code. You've assigned all these properties/values to the very same object. @montrealist, noooooooooooo. Assign the props to a new *(empty)* object `const morar = Object.assign({}, propsToDuplicate, item);`

Comment: @Thomas yes, thank you, I see it now. Or I could simply flip the parameters - would this work? `Object.assign(item, propsToDuplicate); `

Comment: @thomas thats it. Sounds like a good answer to me ...

Comment: @montrealist yes but that would mutate your `items` array. I would always try to prevent such mutation if its not actually useful

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Object.assign(a, b, c)` will assign everything from `a`, `b`, and `c` into the object that is the first parameter to `assign()`.

In your case you are using `propsToDuplicate` as the first parameter, and this means that that each time `assign()` is called, `propsToDuplicate` is being mutated.

Change `const moar = Object.assign(propsToDuplicate, item);` to `const moar = Object.assign({}, propsToDuplicate, item);` and you should be good to go.

Answer (score 1):

> Why do I end up with two instances of the object with num = 2

because `moar === propsToDuplicate` in your code. You've assigned all these properties/values to the very same object. And all indices of that array reference the same object.

> How can I perform this operation so that the final result is as below?

assign the properties to an empty object:

```
const morar = Object.assign({}, propsToDuplicate, item);
```

> The workaround is to return `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(moar));`

this doesn't really work, as you still assign all the properties into the same object, but you return a snapshot of each iteration. If you add another property only to the first object in `items` you'll see it show up for the other(later) items as well.

Plus `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(...))` is a ugly approach to clone an object.

> Or I could simply flip the parameters - would this work? `Object.assign(item, propsToDuplicate);`

yes/no/kind of/better not ... I have to explain.

In that case, you'll overwrite the properties in `item` with the properties in `propsToDuplicate`, and you'd mutate the objects in the `items` array. In your current code this would make no difference, but if some `item` would have a `foo` or `bar` property or if `propsToDuplicate` would contain a `num`, you'd overwrite that property in the result.

explaining that: `Object.assign()` is often used to compose some config object with some default values.

```
let options = Object.assign({}, defaults, config);
```

this will take an empty Object, then first write all the default values into that and then overwrite soem of the default values with the values passed in the config.

whereas

```
let options = Object.assign(config, defaults);
```

will overwrite all the custom configutations with the default values.

Then there's the problem of mutation. The problem with mutation is that depending where you got the object from, and where else it is referenced, you changing the object may introduce errors at the other end of your application, in some completely unrelated peice of code. And then have fun debugging that and finding the error.